# I'm trying to update tasks in a database but it keeps creating new tasks

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to create a feature in the def home(request): view that updates a task if the name already exists in the database. Is this possible? The code is below and help will be much appreciated.

P.S. I wrote an update function below but that also doesn't work in the way that I intend it to. The error was "expecting integer not builtin function".

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User, Permission
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType # the user 
from .models import Task
from .forms import TaskForm

def home(request):

    # add new task
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = str(request.POST['task-name'])
            desc = str(request.POST['task-desc'])
            deadline = request.POST['deadline']

            task = Task(task_name=name, task_desc=desc, task_deadline=deadline)
            if name in Task.objects.filter(task_name=name):
                task.save(update_fields=['task_name', 'task_desc', 'task_deadline'])    
            else:     
                task.save()        

        #messages.success(request, "You've added a task.")
        
        return render(request, 'home.html', {})
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html', {})



def logout_view(request):
    # check if user is logged in when logout button is pressed
    if request.POST.get('logout'):
        print("user has logged out")
        logout(request)
    
    return render(request, 'logout.html', {})


def register(request):
    # collects customer group from database
    customers = Group.objects.get(name='customers')

    customers.has_change_permission(request, obj=Task)
    customers.has_view_permission(request, obj=Task)

    # task_content = ContentType.object.get_for_model(Task)

    # permission = Permission.objects.create(
    #     codename="can_update_tasks",
    #     name="Can Update Tasks",
    #     content_type=task_content
    # )

    
    # adds new user when they submit a form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.POST['first_name']
        lastname = request.POST['last_name']
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        # creates new user
        user = User.objects.create_user(is_superuser=False, username=username, password=password, last_name=lastname, first_name=firstname)

        # adds new user to customer group
        customers.user_set.add(user)

        # saves user data
        user.save()

    return render(request, 'register.html', {})

def login_view(request):

    # sends a request to database for user to login
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        # checks if the username and password entered is in database
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        # checks if user's details exist in the database
        if user is not None:
            #messages.success(request, "Welcome Back!")
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('/')
        else:
            #messages.info(request, "Please register.")
            
            return redirect('register')

    return render(request, 'login.html', {})

def update_task(request):
    # update database using data submitted in form

    f = TaskForm(request.POST)

    if request.POST:
        f = TaskForm(request.POST)

        if f.is_valid():
            task = Task.objects.filter(pk=id)
            f = TaskForm(request.POST, instance=task)
            f.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            task = Task.objects.filter(pk=id)
            f = TaskForm(request.POST, instance=task)

            return render(request, 'update.html', {'form' : f})


    # tasks = []

    # if request.user.is_authenticated:
    #     name = Task.objects.filter(task_name)
    #     desc = Task.objects.filter(task_deadline)
    #     deadline = Task.objects.filter(task_deadline)

    #     tasks.append(name, desc, deadline)
            
    #     return render(request, 'update.html', {'tasks' : tasks})



    return render(request, 'update.html', {'form' : f})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you create a new Task object that is not related to any existing entry in your database table:

```
    task = Task(task_name=name, task_desc=desc, task_deadline=deadline)
```

Then you check if a task with `name` exists:

```
    if name in Task.objects.filter(task_name=name):
```

If it does, you write the new `task` object to the database, creating a new entry.

```
        task.save(update_fields=['task_name', 'task_desc', 'task_deadline'])
```

Otherwise you also create a new entry:

```
    else:     
        task.save()
```

What you probably want to do is to try to find an existing object and update it, or create a new one if no existing object could be found:

```
    try:
        task = Task.objects.get(task_name=name)
    except Task.DoesNotExist:
        task = Task(task_name=name)

    task.task_desc = task_desc
    task.task_deadline = task_deadline
    task.save()
```

Django also has an abbreviaton for this: [`Task.objects.get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)